# Serialize and deserialize the message using google protobuf in socket programming in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, protocol-buffers

Message format to send to server side as below :

```
package test;

message Test {
  required int32 id = 1;
  required string name = 2;
}
```

Server.cpp to do encoding :
               string buffer;

```
           test::Test original;
           original.set_id(0);
           original.set_name("original");

           original.AppendToString(&buffer);
           send(acceptfd,buffer.c_str(), buffer.size(),0);
```

By this send function it will send the data to client,i hope and i am not getting any error also for this particular code.

But my concern is like below:

1. How to decode using Google Protocol buffer for the above message in
   the client side
2. So that i can see/print the message.

Comment: Do you really need `AppendToString()` ? Are you appending `original` message to any other message? If not, why don't you consider just `SerializeToString()` ? I'm just curious. (*)

Answer (score 1):

You should send more than just the protobuf message to be able to decode it on the client side.

A simple solution would be to send the value of `buffer.size()` over the socket as a 4-byte integer using network byte order, and the send the buffer itself.

The client should first read the buffer's size from the socket and convert it from network to host byte order. Let's denote the resulting value `s`. The client must then preallocate a buffer of size `s` and read `s` bytes from the socket into it. After that, just use MessageLite::ParseFromString to reconstruct your protobuf.

See [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite) for more info on protobuf message methods.

Also, [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) document discourages the usage of `required`:

> You should be very careful about marking fields as required. If at
>   some point you wish to stop writing or sending a required field, it
>   will be problematic to change the field to an optional field – old
>   readers will consider messages without this field to be incomplete and
>   may reject or drop them unintentionally. You should consider writing
>   application-specific custom validation routines for your buffers
>   instead. Some engineers at Google have come to the conclusion that
>   using required does more harm than good; they prefer to use only
>   optional and repeated. However, this view is not universal.

Comment: I am able to print only id not able to print the name by using the below code :

Comment: You might want to use pastebin to share code. Comments aren't really good for that. Just post the pastebin link in the comments.

Comment: Go to http://pastebin.com/, paste your code in the text field, click submit. It will take you to a new page. Copy the link to that page here in the comments.

Comment: How to do both serialization/encoding and deserialization/decoding for a message using google protobuf ..any idea ?